# How to i set jqplot bar chart colours per bar?

Tags: colors, jqplot

I'm trying to set the colours of my jqplot bar chart bars. There will always be six bars present, grouped into sets of 2 bars. Here is an example of the data being plotted:

```
 line1 = [6000, 5000, 5500];
 line2 = [16000, 10000, 14000];
```

I've used the following so far:

```
 seriesColors: ["#F3CBBF", "#BFDDE5", "#CF3501", "#027997", "#CF3501", "#027997"],
```

But jqplot alternates between the first 2 bars each time instead of using all of the declared colours. This is probably as it only determines 2 series being present, one per set of data.

Is there a way to set the bar colours explicitly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I do this using the [varyBarColor method](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-barRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.BarRenderer.varyBarColor) so you can list the different colours for the bars in a simple array like you have done already but if there is only one series it will use these colors for each bar instead. Here is an example of my code:

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
        title: 'Example Income Graph',
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions:{ varyBarColor : true },
            pointLabels: { show : true }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                label:'Net Growth (%)',
                ticks: ticks
            },
            yaxis:{
              label:'Income (&pound;)',
              tickOptions:{ formatString:'%d'},
              autoscale:true,
              min:0, 
              max:10000
            }
        },
        seriesColors: [ "#eee", "#ccc", "#999"],
        highlighter: { show: false }
    });
```

In this graph I had one series with 3 bars and they are each a different colour grey.

Comment: this answer doesnt really explain how to achieve what the TO asked for. His question was about multiple series and manually specifying each single bar's colors

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty old, but still doesn't have the right answer, and it took me a while to figure it out, so here it goes.

You need two things:
Set the varyBarColor and a series array that contains the series colors for each series, passed at the same level as seriesDefaults, such as:

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2], {
            title: 'Example',
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions:{ varyBarColor : true },
                pointLabels: { show : true }
            },
            series: [{seriesColors: ["#F3CBBF", "#BFDDE5", "#CF3501"]},
                     {seriesColors: ["#027997", "#CF3501", "#027997"]}]
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer , seriesColors: ["#F3CBBF", "#BFDDE5", #CF3501","#eee", "#ccc", "#999"] }]
```