# jqplot change the color of a single marker

Tags: colors, jqplot, marker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to i set jqplot bar chart colours per bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144442/how-to-i-set-jqplot-bar-chart-colours-per-bar)

Does anyone know the best way to change the color of a single marker in jqplot? I need to highlight two markers, setting the highest value to one color, and the lowest to another. There was a similar thread on Google groups but no answers (http://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/e17a8b22860757ca?pli=1).

Thanks

David

Comment: Yikes... I didn't do a very good job of researching first! Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144442/how-to-i-set-jqplot-bar-chart-colours-per-bar